# How to find angle in circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

[image]

I have done question $(a)$ but cannot do question $(b)$.

Does anyone have any solutions or ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Tell us, what *is* your solution for (a)? It might be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let  $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. $\angle CAM=\alpha/4$.

$$\sin\frac{\alpha}{4}=\frac{BC/2}{AC}=\frac{r/2}{2r}=\frac{1}{4}$$

[image]

Comment: From this how do you show $\alpha = 4\arcsin\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\triangle ABC$. By cosine rule,

$$\begin{align*}
BC^2 &= AB^2 + AC^2 - 2 AB\cdot AC\cos\angle BAC\\
r^2 &= 4r^2 + 4r^2 - 8r^2\cos\angle BAC\\
8\cos \angle BAC &= 7\\
\cos\angle BAC &= \frac 78\\
1 - 2\sin^2\frac{\angle BAC}2 &= \frac 78\\
\sin^2\frac{\angle BAC}2 &= \frac1{16}\\
\sin\frac{\angle BAC}2 &= \frac14 \quad\text{(positive square root taken)}\\
\angle BAC &= 2\arcsin \frac14\\
\alpha &= 4\arcsin \frac14
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: for a) use that $$A=\frac{r^2}{2}(x-\sin(x))$$